# Matching two strings in VBA, transporting other cell values to a different location

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro that utilizes a userform to define a value that I need to reference later on in the program (Val1). The macro needs to go into a particular spreadsheet, look through several headings, and if the values match, it needs to copy all of the data in that column and paste it into a different spreadsheet in the same workbook.

At current, I get a

> Run-Time error 1004 'Select Method of Range Class Failed'

at the `cell.End(xlDown).Select`

```
public NewSheetName as string, val1 as string
    Dim f As Range
Set f = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1:L1")

For Each cell In f
    If cell = val1 Then
    cell.End(xlDown).Select
    selection.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NewSheetName).Range("B1")
'NewSheetName is defined elsewhere
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What is `val1` and `NewSheetName`? Are they defined?

Comment: Defined in the Public statement above. NewSheetName is derived from an inputbox (that creates a new sheet) and val1 is derived from a field in the userform.

Comment: Title says matching TWO strings... which two? As I understand it, you're simply searching for val1 in the first row of a specified range?

Comment: `cell.End(xlDown).Select` selects a single cell.

Comment: Yes, trying to match 'val1' and a cell in range 'f'.

Comment: `Range(cell, Range(cell).End(xlDown)).Select` is another approach that I've tried in place of `cell.End(xlDown).Select` but it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach which avoids looping:

```
Sub foo(ByVal sVal1 As String, ByVal sSheetName As String)
    Dim c As Range

    Set c = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1:L1").Find(what:=sVal1)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Range(c, c.End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sSheetName).Range("B1")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for.
I first find `match` which will be the column letter of what you are searching for.

Then I copy the column and paste the values.
No looping is needed.

```
on error resume next ' if nothing is found it creates an error
match = Split(Cells(1, Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find(what:=val1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True).Column).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
on error goto 0
if match = "" or match > "L" then
    msgbox "nothing found in range"
else
    Range(match & ":" & match).Copy ' copies column "E:E" for example
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NewSheetName).Range("B1").Select ' selects output cell
    ActiveSheet.Paste ' paste
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

- Build a new Excel Workbook with 2 worksheets;
- On the first one, in range `B1:L1` write the word "something" 3-4 times;
- Write other random things at range `B2:L10`;

Run this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim val1 As String: val1 = "something"
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim f As Range

    Set f = Worksheets(1).Range("B1:L1")

    For Each cell In f
        If cell = val1 Then
            cell.End(xlDown).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(2).Range(cell.Address)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

It loops through `Range(B1:L1)` of the first worksheet and if it finds the word `something` there, it copies the range to the second worksheet.